# При изменении счетчика должен изменится span

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Доброго времени суток!
Нужна помощь с динамическим изменение span при смене атрибута у счетчика (aria-valuenow)
Значения span должно быть в массиве
Сам код JQuery для изменения счетчика

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
var arrText = ["450 гр.", "900 гр.","2270 гр.","4540 гр."];
 
$(function() {
    $("#spinner-tovar-1-gramm").textSpinner({
        values: arrText
    });
});
 
});
```

Код счетчика HTML

```
    <span class="ui-spinner ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<input id="spinner-tovar-1-gramm" value="0" readonly="" aria-valuenow="1" autocomplete="off" class="ui-spinner-input" role="spinbutton">
<input class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up" id="buttonup" type="button" value="">
<input class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-down" id="buttondown" type="button" value="">
</span>
```

Т.е. например если атрибут счетчика aria-valuenow="0", то текст span будешь содержать 1000, если ="1" , то 2000 и т.д. И все это происходит динамично

Помогите пожалуйста , а то совсем запутался

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это плагин  jQuery UI 1.12.1

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#spinner-tovar-1-gramm').on('change',function(){
    $('#id вашего спана').html($('#spinner-tovar-1-gramm').attr('aria-valuenow'));
});
```

Comment: Как я понял , спан принимает значение атрибута?

Comment: Но мне надо чтобы при изменение атрибута счетчика менялся span. Например если aria-valuenow="0" , тогда span.text('1000') , но лучше чтобы текст span брался из массива)